# Calculate Total Hrs spent given intime and outtime using Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have to calculate total hours spent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9gOY.jpg)

I have attached Excel(img) which shows the data format.

I have tried for some code as below"

```
For k = 2 To rowval:

    InTime = Rows(k).Cells(1, 6).Value
    OutTime = Rows(k).Cells(1, 7).Value

    If InTime <> "" And OutTime <> "" Then    
        a = Val(InTime)
        b = Val(OutTime)
        time = b - a
```

For some values instead of getting **3.516666667** as output am getting **3** as output.

Can anybody please help me to get the appropriate output?

Comment: Using your way I think it only takes into account the digits before the ":" sign. You will need to convert to minutes before calculating the time spent.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use VBA for this calculation. You can just use a basic vba forumla in the Total Hrs Field as below.

=TEXT(G2-F2,"hh:mm")

If you want to do this in VBA then you can also use this formula in your VBA code with something like this:

time = TEXT(b-a,"hh:mm")

The trick here is including "hh:mm" which tells excel how to format the result.

Best